# Conceptual proof of Riemann–Hurwitz formula

Tags: general-topology

Lately I came across the very interesting [Riemann–Hurwitz formula](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Riemann-Hurwitz_formula). I believe I understand the claim of the formula, but I do not understand well why this formula is true.

I am looking for some conceptual proof, or at least some intuition for the Riemann–Hurwitz formula.

I am not a mathematician, but a physicist, and not an expert in the field of topology. Explantions using lighter notations and definitions would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: See Gubkin's proof [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/99292/question-regarding-riemann-hurwitz-formula-proof). Did you understand the argument? This is the most hands-on proof of the RH formula that exist.

Comment: Thank you @moishe, this answer helps. I am still not completely sure why the difference between the number of vertexes is exactly is the sum of $k-1$, I will think of it more soon.
I wonder if there is even more intuitive proves if we look on specific spaces, like tori and spheres.

Comment: I suggest you first verify the formula for the number of vertices in some simple examples and then think about the general case. If you cannot prove it in general, ping me and I will write an answer.

Comment: Thank you very much @moishe, it is very kind of you!
After thinking of it more I think I do understand it for simple cases. I am not completely sure how to prove it in general, but I guess the same basic idea is true also for spaces that are harder to imagine.
If you are not too busy I'll be glad to see a proof, but please do not feel committed just because I asked.